# Display all Post titles with Category and Tag

Tags: get-posts

I am trying to display all posts that are in a specific category and have a specific tag.  This is what I have so far but it seems to ignore the & and make it or.

```
<?php
$myposts = get_posts( "cat=the_field('troubleshooting_category')&tag_id=5" );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

The first line

```
$myposts = get_posts( "cat=the_field('troubleshooting_category')&tag_id=5" );
```

properly converts to

```
$myposts = get_posts( "cat=4&tag_id=5" );
```

but instead of displaying all posts with category id of 4 and tag id of 5 it is displaying all that have either one (I need it to display only those with both)

Comment: Make use of a `tax_query` to do this type of query :-)

Comment: Of note, `WP_Query` would be more efficient here, unlike `WP_Query`, the results of `get_posts()` are not cached via Advanced Post Cache, use `WP_Query` instead, or set `'suppress_filters' => false`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment, the best approach here will be to make use of a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). You have much more flexibility and the ability to run more complex queries specially when you are working with more than one taxonomy (in this case `category` and `post_tag`).

You can try something like this

```
$args = [
    'tax_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'taxonomy'         => 'category',
            'field'            => 'term_id',
            'terms'            => the_field('troubleshooting_category'),
            'exclude_children' => true
        ],
        [
            'taxonomy'         => 'post_tag',
            'field'            => 'term_id',
            'terms'            => 5,
        ],
    ],
];
$q = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the Tax_Query advice.  I have done the following and it works perfectly.

```
    $myquery['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms' => array('category-slug'),
        'field' => 'slug',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'terms' => array('tag-slug'),
        'field' => 'slug',
    ),
);
query_posts($myquery);
```

Comment: Never ever make use of `query_posts`. It is just a really bad function to use. Please take note of @TomJNowell comment to your question

Comment: I will go ahead and try to make the changes taking into consideration @TomJNowell's comment.  Thank you all for your support and I will post my final solution when I have a moment later to go back to it.

Comment: Your original use of `get_posts` was better practice than `query_posts`

Comment: This is for internal use and part of a knowledgebase that I am putting together and as such the answer above works.  This said I am looking into the wp_query instead of query_posts to follow best practice.  I usually don't get so deep in Wordpress and do sites like this custom PHP.  Thank you all for your advice as I learn the difference between all of these functions. (the -1 seems harsh since while not best practice it does work)

Comment: I have downvoted this not because I don't say that your code does not work, I downvoted it because your code is bad practice, working or not, period. Remember, your post should be a reference for everyone, not just for you. Note, downvotes can be removed if the post is appropriatly edited :-)